# Getting a number from interest equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Here is the question for my homework:

A mother wants to invest $\$7000.00$ for her son's future education. She invests a portion of the money in a bank certificate of deposit (CD account) which earns $4\%$ and the remainder in a savings bond that earns $7\%$. If the total interest earned after one year is $\$420.00$, how much money was invested in the CD account?

Now, here is my steps:

Amount invested in the savings bond can be represented as $7000 - x$

The interest earned in one year on the CD account is $0.04x$

So, the interest earned on the savings bond in one year can be represented as: $0.07(7000-x)$

The total interested earned after one year is $\$420.00$

The equation is now $0.04x+0.07(7000-x) = 420.00$

Now to SIMPLFY it.

I have this so far

$n - 420 = 0.03x$

How do I get the number $n$?

Comment: Shouldn't your n just be the .07*7000 that you left out in your last line?

Comment: @Dan: The solution of your eq. $0.04x+0.07(7000-x)=420.00$ is $x=\frac{7000}{3}\approx 2333.33$. Since the LHS,  $0.04x+0.07(7000-x)=490.0-0.03x$, you have the equivalent eq. $490.0-0.03x=420.00$ or $490.0-420.00=0.03x$, the solution of which is $x=\frac{490.0-420.00}{0.03}=\frac{7000}{3}\approx 2333.33$ USD.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what n is supposed to represent but instead of it you should still have that 7000*.07. Now you are left with just a number on the left and you can proceed to solve for x. $$.07(7000)-420.00 = 0.03x$$

Comment: YEs, I got that now. How do you solve this?

Comment: I mean what do I do now?

Comment: Well you should be able to simplify the left hand side to just a number and so to get x by itself you will then divide both sides by .03. Does this help? If not what are you getting stuck on? From your original question you seem to have a pretty good idea of what is going on and what you need to do.

Comment: OK so then I do .07(7000) which gets me 490 and then I do 490-420 which gets me 70 and FINALLY I do 70/.03 which gets me the answer of 2333.33 ! :D

Comment: Yes! :) So to summarize she will invest 2333.33 in the CD account and the rest (7000-2333.33) in savings bonds to earn exactly 420 dollars of interest in a year.